# Added a route and the behaviour changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to optimize the appearance of the URL like below:

http://localhost:3817/Affaire/SearchAffaires?OnlyFavorite=True

So I added a new route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Search Affaire Only Favorite", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/OnlyFavorite", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires", OnlyFavorite = true } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now the URL is easier to read:

http://localhost:3817/Affaire/SearchAffaires/OnlyFavorite

But a new problem is occured: the other links on my page have changed because of the routing!

Example here:  .../Affaire/SearchAffaires?LabelName=Baxter&OnlyLabel=True&**OnlyFavorite=True**

Before it was: .../Affaire/SearchAffaires?LabelName=Baxter&OnlyLabel=True

As you can see, the variable **OnlyFavorite** has been added to the URL. Finally I found the reason of this behaviour: the routing system is keen to make a match against a route, to the extent that it will reuse segment variable values from the incoming URL. The best way to deal with this behavior is to prevent it from happening. It is strongly recommend that you
do not rely on this behaviour, and that you supply values for all of the segment variables in a URL pattern.

That's a little bit annoying because I have a lot of variables!

Any solution on that problem? Why is that behaviour not happening whith one single route (the default one)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I've registering routes like this, i get away from problem:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search Affaire", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires" } // Parameter defaults
    );
routes.MapRoute(
        "Search Affaire Only Favorite", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/OnlyFavorite", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires", OnlyFavorite = true } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: you didn't have any problem because routes are applied in the order in which they appear in the RouteCollection. The second one (in this case) is never reachable. This is not a solution.

Comment: that is not true, as i've tested and localhost/affaire/searchaffaires/onlyfavorite works.